# Test Coverage for Current Page Id

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, callout, failing-tests

not sure what I am doing wrong here with setting the page id in the test class. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? The failed test is throwing `System.NullPointerException: Argument 1 cannot be null` on line  `ecpc.creditPullandReRender();`

```
public static testMethod void successtestLeadCreditPullandReRender(){
    //inserting the data
    EquifaxCreditPull__c post = new EquifaxCreditPull__c(APIKey__c = '132', Endpoint__c = 'test', Token__c = 'test');
    insert post;
    Lead l = new Lead(FirstName = 'Test', LastName = 'Test2', Social_Security_Number__c = '000000000', SSN_Encrypted__c = '000000000', Company = 'TestCo');
    insert l;
    Consumer_Credit_Summary__c ccs = new Consumer_Credit_Summary__c(FICO__c = 123, Transaction_Date__c = Date.today());
    insert ccs;

    //creating the mock callout
    SingleRequestMockClass fakeResponse = new SingleRequestMockClass(200,'Complete','{"ResultStatus":"Success"}',null);

    //setting the page id
    PageReference pageRef = Page.EquifaxCreditPullAccountPage;
    pageRef.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(l.Id));
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

    //calling the controller and passing it the lead as the standard object
    EquifaxCreditPullController ecpc = new EquifaxCreditPullController(new Apexpages.StandardController(l));

    Test.startTest();
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, fakeResponse);
    ecpc.creditPullandReRender();
    Test.stopTest();
    System.assert(true);
    System.assertNotEquals(null, fakeResponse,'{"ResultStatus":"Success"}');
}



public void creditPullandReRender(){
    String currentPageId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    if(currentPageId.startsWith('001')) { //account
        string selectedContactID = paramValue;
        System.debug('selectedContactID :'+ selectedContactID);
        pullCred(null, selectedContactID, null);
    }
    else if(currentPageId.startsWith('00Q')) { //lead
        pullCred(currentPageId, null, null);
    }
    else if(currentPageId.startsWith('a1jm')) { //credit review
        pullCred(null, null, currentPageId);
    }
    dataLoad();
}
```

I can see with debugs that the page is being set correctly in the test. Why would the page ID not carry over to the method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple notes:

- Don't ever include `system.assert(true)` in your tests (nor any other assertion which cannot fail). It reads as an attempt to circumvent static analysis scans of your code quality.
- There is no need to call `Test.setCurrentPage` or construct a `PageReference`. You don't care what the current page is, just its parameters. So use:

  ```
  ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', value);
  ```
- You should not check the `SObjectType` of your `Id` using string prefix values. Instead, cast it to an `Id` proper and call the `getSObjectType` method:

  ```
  Id currentPageId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
  SObjectType currentPageType = (currentPageId == null) ?
      null : currentPageId.getSObjectType();
  if (currentPageType == Account.sObjectType)
  {
      // do stuff
  }
  // etc
  ```

  This approach has numerous advantages, including but not limited to a hard reference to that sObjectType, allowing various parts of the system to understand that your code is dependent on that object's existence. It also makes your code more human readable without comments.

As for your specific error, it seems like the `pullCred` method may not accept one or all of the null parameters you pass in. Further investigative steps include:

- pulling the complete stack trace string
- checking how you use the parameters in your `pullCred` method and if you should allow null inputs

Comment: all great advice. thank you. I ended up finding that it was the custom setting that was causing an issue.  Once I updated it in the test class everything was passing. so for those who are curious, the test was written correctly it was a custom setting declaration issue.